# corr(xz, yz) given all pairwise correlations

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose we have random variables $x,y,z$ where each random variable has mean 0 and standard deviation of 1. $Corr(x,y) = a$, $corr(x,z)=b$ and $corr(y,z)=c$

How do I go about calculating $corr(xz, yz)$? For multivariate normal there should be an exact answer, does it hold for other distributions?

Comment: Can we assume mutual independence here, or are you looking for an expression in terms of the linear dependence between x, y and z?

Comment: Because the correlation of $xz$ and $yz$ depends on the expectation of $xzyz=xyz^2$ (a multivariate fourth moment), it cannot be calculated except when you assume enough about the distributions to determine that fourth moment.  Although this is the case for multivariate normals, whose means and variances determine all moments, it is not generally true.